# Route in the table: "default from A::/48 via fe80:: dev X .." ip -6 route

Tags: iproute

How do I need to set a route using `ip` such that the output of `ip -6 route show` looks as follows:

```
default from 2001::/64 dev X  proto static  metric 1024
```

This was result on the Open-WRT router with `using ip -6 route show` command. So I want to repeat the same rule but for manual network prefix.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
ip -6 route add default via 2001::/64 dev X
```

as described in the EXAMPLES section of `ip-route(8)`.

Comment: According to the EXAMPLE ip address of next-hop(gateway) mentioned after "via" argument. Such that result command from example looks like "ip -6 route add default via 2001:xxxx:...:1 dev X"
Result in routing table of such example execution is:
"default via 2001:xxxx:...:1 dev X metric 1024" that is obviously not the same as in the topic message. Maybe you can suggest what exactly should be written to get output of the command "ip -6 route" as presented in the topic?